# Obligation Tactic := intros. results in the Program Fixpoint with measure not being defined

Tags: coq

I have a Program Fixpoint with measure for which I have proved all obligations. When I try to check it, it fails:

> Error: The reference trivial_program_fixpoint2 was not found in the
> current environment.

I have narrowed the error to the use of a non default tactic to prove obligations.
In the code below, the first `Program` is defined. Once I choose a non default tactic to prove `Obligation`s, the `Program` doesn't get defined even though there are no `Obligation`'s left to prove. I would expect `trivial_program_fixpoint2` to be defined after `Qed`.

I have looked in the [documentation](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/program.html#coq:cmd.Obligation-Tactic) but I don't see anything that suggests that using a tactic different than default would change what I am seeing.

Coq version used:

> The Coq Proof Assistant, version 8.15+alpha compiled with OCaml 4.09.1

Below is code to reproduce the problem.

```
From Coq Require Export Arith.
Require Import Program.Wf.

Program Fixpoint trivial_program_fixpoint (n : nat) {measure n}: nat :=
  match n with
    0 => 0
  | m => m
  end.
Check trivial_program_fixpoint.

Obligation Tactic := intros.

Program Fixpoint trivial_program_fixpoint2 (n : nat) {measure n}: nat :=
  match n with
    0 => 0
  | m => m
  end.
Next Obligation.
  intuition. discriminate.
Qed.
Check trivial_program_fixpoint2.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second `Program Fixpoint` produced two obligations.

```
trivial_program_fixpoint2 has type-checked, generating 2 obligations

Solving obligations automatically...

2 obligations remaining
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought Qed was used when no obligations are left.

Comment: @RolandCoeurjoly `Qed` is accepted when no goals are left. The obligations generated by `Program` work a little differently. I don't know why this is. One consequence is that each solved obligation becomes a defined object in its own right, and one can choose whether to close them with `Defined` or `Qed`.

Comment: `Program` is different (obligations are not generated as subgoals) *because* it lets you choose whether to make the obligations transparent or not.